# ATI 12.1 driver fails after logout

Tags: 11.10, ati, login, logout

Yesterday I have upgraded my ATI proprietary driver to 12.1. After some small issues it installed correctly, I have confirmation in Catalyst that the driver is at version 12.1.

Today I have noticed that after each log out, when I try to log back in, the screen freezes on my wallpaper. The mouse is working fine. CTRL-ALT-Backspace resets the Xserver, and prompts me back to the log in page. If I try a login, same thing happens. If I reboot from the login screen, I can log in into Unity 3D without any issue.

The issues happen only if I try to log-out and then back in. If I log in on Ubuntu 2D, it works fine.

So, any Ideas?

Edit:
I think that's what's happening when I try to re-login. Taken from /var/log/syslog:

```
gnome-session[3017]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.#012
 kernel: [ 1124.496537] [fglrx] IRQ 49 Disabled
```

Edit 2:

I have reverted to the drivers 11.12 and 11.10 (currently using it) and the behavior is the same. The problem is that I don't remember if I had this problem before or not. I would guess not, so, something is wrong here. It's not a show stopper for me, because I don't need to log-out / log-in, but still it's an error.

Comment: Kind of off-subject, but is it worth the upgrade for any different features?

Comment: I was told an old issue in Gnome Shell has been fixed with this driver. A screen flicker.

Comment: Oh, did you have problems running Mint on it too? I'm on a 8,3 MBP and the display manager flicker and restart now and again, which is why I was forced to go with Ubuntu/Unity.

Comment: didn't try mint, sorry

Comment: I upgraded recently and it totally borked Bluetooth on my system in addition to suspend/resume. I'm waiting for the 12.2 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Hang_at_logout

Basically, something hangs and you need to force it to shut down when logging out. Might also apply at shutdown/hibernate. I had these issues before, but aren't experiencing them now.

Comment: reading now...certainly in the right direction. Be back with info shortly.

Comment: unfortunately the fix from the link didn't work for me. Too bad, it was a good lead. But +1 for the help.

Comment: Try watching your computer as it logs out. Run `sleep 10 ; gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt` then hit CTRL+ALT+F5 to switch to another TTY. Log in, then `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. Why not? ;)

Comment: how :) where could I log what it's doing?

Comment: Should I be worried that in /etc/X11 I don't have a xorg.conf file? I have a bunch of xorg.conf.fglrx-0/1/2... and xorg.conf.original-0/1

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Try doing `sudo aticonfig --initial`.

Comment: I have re-created the xorg.conf. Please see the Edit in my original post.

Comment: I had to do a lot of tweaking for my card to make xorg.conf persistent.  I really don't remember what I did, but the result was essentially telling canonical to leave my xorg.conf the hell alone.  I needed to manually specify 3 monitor orientation with xinerama in my case.  I suspect you need to find a way to do the same, on telling canonical to leave a statically generated file alone that is.